# How to allocate large volume(of the order of GBs) of memory in c?

Tags: c

I am trying to use malloc in c language for allocating large volume of data us.When I increase the array size beyond certain value the program terminates saying "program.c" stopped working.I would like to know the correct way of assigning large volume of data(Here it is 4GB) to variables in general in c.I am using 64 bit windows on 32GB RAM .Here is the code for reference.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<math.h>
   #include<conio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   double** Allocate(int d1,int d2);
   double** Allocate(int d1,int d2)
   {  
      double **m;
      int i,j;
      m = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*d1);  
      for(i=0;i<d1;i++)
      {
       m[i]=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*d2);
      }
     for(i=0;i<d1;i++)
       {
        for(j=0;j<d2;j++)
         {
           m[i][j]=0.0;
         }
       }
     return m;
   }
   main()
   {
    int i,j;
    int n=2.2e4;
    double** A= Allocate(n,n);  
    printf("Memory allocation successful");
   }
```

Comment: It would seem that you have reached some memory limit. Why not try and break down your program so it would not need all of the data in memory at once?

Comment: Shloim,Thanks for the idea.So I understand I ll  have to break the domain if  I don't have any other choice.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit windows?   The total addressable memory on a 32-bit system is typically limited to 4GB - and the OS as well as other programs consume part of that.   Also, have you tried checking the values returned by individual `malloc()` calls, to track how much is *actually* being allocated before a failure occurs?

Comment: @Peter  64 bit windows.The memory requested amounts roughly to 4 GB.I did not check individual malloc calls.Can you please brief me what it is?

Comment: Read the documentation for `malloc()`.  It returns `NULL` if it fails.  Your code, as shown, does not check for that.

Comment: @Tilak Mallikarjun: Have you verified that you are compiling a 64-bit executable and not a 32-bit one. Otherwise you are still bound to the old limits, even on a 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted program works fine on a machine with 64-bit Windows and 8GB of RAM. The amount of RAM you have doesn't have anything to do with it, on a demand-paged virtual memory operating system your program allocates *address space*.  You don't use RAM until you start using the address space, happens when you set the array elements to 0.  You can never run out of RAM.

The most obvious reason why you can't allocate the address space is because your program runs in 32-bit mode.  You must select the x64 platform for your project.  If you use VS then use Build > Configuration Manager > Active solution platform combobox.  Technically you could make it work in 32-mode by using the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker option (doubles the address space from 2GB to 4GB) but there isn't any real point in doing that.

How much address space you can allocate ultimately depends on the size of the paging file and how fast the OS can grow it.  With 32GB of installed RAM you are not close to that limit yet.

Comment: Thank you.when i changed  compiler option from 32 bit mode to 64 bit mode it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating `3e5*3e5 = 9e10` doubles, which represents `720 Go` assuming a double is 8 octet.

Comment: Thanku faibbus .I tried 2.2e4 *2.2e4 which amounts to 4 GB which didn't work.Generally for CFD calculations that size is common adding memory required for all other variables in 3 Dimensions.